# Gravity Forms critical error when populating

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

hope somebody can guide me, I tried google and I am still lost. I tried `strval` but keep getting the same error. `$structure_code` is for example `22334455`

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_construction_company', 'populate_site_client' );

function populate_site_client($value) {
    $structure_code = strval($_GET['structure_code']);
    echo gettype($structure_code);
    $structure_id = get_page_by_title($structure_code, OBJECT, 'structures');
   return $structure_id;
}
```

When adding this, I get the error:

`Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/scaffaudit/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1098`

Comment: wordpress manual says on the `get_page_by_title` = `(WP_Post|array|null) WP_Post (or array) on success, or null on failure.` you're probably echoing `$structure_id` somewhere, you probably need to echo a property inside it, not echo the object itself

Comment: `echo gettype($structure_code);` this is the second line in your code. Remove that. Also, the error is pretty specific if that's line 1098 in your code.